# NSMutableAttributedString lost attribute with assign to a UITextView on iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview

I needs to develop a app that can do some syntax highlight for patch file, and it highly depends on NSMutableAttributedString which added in iOS6, so I create a master/detail view to show the file, with a processor class, which add highlight attribute for each line of text, but when I assign this attributeString to the UITextView.attributeString, I found all attribute that was lost.

My code is like this:

```
- (IBAction)ColorIconClicked:(id)sender {

NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc
                                   ] initWithAttributedString:self.textView.attributedText];
self.textView.text = nil;
[self.textView setEditable:YES];
[[processor processPatchText:str withTheme:COLOR_TEXT_THEME_DAY suggestFormat:@"diffu"] attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

self.textView.attributedText = str;

NSLog(@"|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");

NSLog(@"STD: %@", str);
NSLog(@"-----------------------------");
NSLog(@"%@", self.textView.attributedText);

[self.textView setEditable:NO];
}
```

The log I have capture is below:

This is the dump of "str" before assign:

```
2012-10-19 01:12:42.863 ColorDiff[354:907] |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
2012-10-19 01:12:42.883 ColorDiff[354:907] STD: diff --git a/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m b/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}index 3e554fa..18723b2 100644{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}--- a/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+++ b/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}@@ -15,9 +15,19 @@{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} // git format-patch or something like svn or raw diff output.{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} //{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} // then it should call the different render to do the actually render job.{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}-- (NSMutableAttributedString *) processPatchText:(NSMutableAttributedString*) attstring withTheme: (int) theme suggestFormat:(NSString *) format{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+- (NSMutableAttributedString *) processPatchText:(NSMutableAttributedString *) attstring{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+                                       withTheme:(int) theme{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}

{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+ * This function return the patch format for the input text.{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+ * return type should be like: diffu, diffc, etc, aligh with colordiff.pl{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+ */{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+- (NSString *) detechPatchFormatForText:(NSMutableAttributedString *) attstring{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+{{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+    {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}+}{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

But after assign:

The dump of textView's attribute like this

```
"NSLog(@"%@", self.textView.attributedText);" is become:
2012-10-19 01:12:42.924 ColorDiff[354:907] -----------------------------
2012-10-19 01:12:42.991 ColorDiff[354:907] diff --git a/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m b/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m
index 3e554fa..18723b2 100644
--- a/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m
+++ b/ColorDiff/CDTextProcessor.m
@@ -15,9 +15,19 @@
// git format-patch or something like svn or raw diff output.
//
// then it should call the different render to do the actually render job.
-- (NSMutableAttributedString *) processPatchText:(NSMutableAttributedString*) attstring withTheme: (int) theme suggestFormat:(NSString *) format
+- (NSMutableAttributedString *) processPatchText:(NSMutableAttributedString *) attstring
+                                       withTheme:(int) theme
+                                   suggestFormat:(NSString *) format
{

}

+/*
+ * This function return the patch format for the input text.
+ * return type should be like: diffu, diffc, etc, aligh with colordiff.pl
+ */
+- (NSString *) detechPatchFormatForText:(NSMutableAttributedString *) attstring
+{
+   
+}
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x210595f0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

It's the attribute of str is lost when assign the self.textView.attributedText of textView.

Why ?

This is a BUG ?

How can I assign the attribute string of to a textView ?

Answer (score 0):

These is no BUG in iOS, it's caused by my programming error, so the attribute actually not have right attributed with different color, after fix it, the program works again.